# Remove password checking when using user registration form

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I want to create user and generate password automatically. I am using custom form class for displaying first name, lastname and email fields. Username is created based on email and there is no issue with this. However i cannot skip password validation and implement password generation when saving new user.

Should I create custom validator.xml

original one is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="fos_user.validator.password.class">FOS\UserBundle\Validator\PasswordValidator</parameter>
        <parameter key="fos_user.validator.unique.class">FOS\UserBundle\Validator\UniqueValidator</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="fos_user.validator.initializer" class="FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Initializer" public="false">
            <tag name="validator.initializer" />
            <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager" />
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

I see here `fos_user.validator.password.class`, maybe I should place here custom class

Ok i'm close to solution, using validator.xml I can change some validators, but I have no idea how I can change `NotBlank` validator to `Blank`. Tried this snippet without success.

```
    <class name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User">

        <property name="plainPassword">
            <constraint name="Blank">
                <option name="groups">Registration</option>
            </constraint>
        </property>

    </class>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that overloading already defined constraints is not possible at all. For this reason many people recommend using validation groups to control this. Of course for this example it is a bad idea because there are many validation rules that need to be copy-pasted into new group.

For this reason I decided to create some hidden field for password and fill it with some random value that will be used for generating the real one.